# Exporting template to every sheet AND columns to separate sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook for creating school report cards. With the help of @user3598756, who kindly introduced me to the Dictionary approach, I now have a working macro for exporting columns of information from an Input sheet to new sheets. D1 to D63 now appears on sheet2 in column D, column E1 to E63 now appears in column D on sheet 3, and so on (with the new sheets having the students names from row 7). Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()
    Dim studsSht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim stud As Variant

    Set studsSht = Worksheets("Input") '<--| change "Sheet1" to your actual students grades sheet
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| instantiate a Dictionary object
        For Each cell In studsSht.Range("D7:Q7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through students names (change "D7:Q7" to your actual range with students names)
            .item(cell.Value) = .item(cell.Value) & cell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False) & "," '<--| add or update the dictionary entry whose key is the current student name with its corresponding column address
        Next
        For Each stud In .keys '<--| loop through unique students names
            Intersect(studsSht.UsedRange, studsSht.Range(Left(.item(stud), Len(.item(stud)) - 1))).Copy Destination:=GetSheet(CStr(stud)).Range("D1") '<--| copy its columns to correspondingly named sheet starting from cell D1
        Next
    End With

    studsSht.Activate
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    End If
End Function
```

I would, however, also like to copy the basic template part of my input page (A1:C63) to **every** new sheet, and in the same macro. While there are a number of macros to copy a basic template, I'm finding it difficult to integrate them. Through trial and error I have had mixed results; one new student page with both template and student data, the rest with only student data (and blank in the first three columns), or a bunch of extra unnecessary sheets with only the template.

The macro above does a good job of creating a new sheet only where a student name is present in row 7 on the input sheet (and so I don't have to edit the macro for an input sheet with fewer or more students). I'd like the new part of the macro that transposes the first three columns to be reactive to this feature, and this is where I'm stuck.

Any advice for a relative newb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just include it in your GetSheet function (I am assuming you want it in the same location of each sheet):

```
Function GetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
    GetSheet.Name = shtName
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C63").Copy
    GetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlAll
End If
End Function
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I asked for, and a whole bunch has been learned about how crap I am at programming in the process. Ha! Thanks. However, I haven't preserved the column widths from the Input sheet. I'll try to modify it myself, but if I struggle, may I post my issues here again?

Comment: So I tried recording a macro and selecting the relevant information from it, then pasting it into my function. `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` Again, I have the problem of having one new sheet with the template and all column widths, borders and colours preserved, but called 'Sheet 1' and the new sheets with just information and no template. Sorry. I am bad at this.

Comment: I updated the code to paste values and format. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It's almost perfect! Just on little hiccough (http://imgur.com/a/ZDOVb) Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do. The new pages should look like the input page but only go as far as column D (which they do). The student in column D on the input page appears in column D on sheet 2. The student in column E moves over to column D on sheet three, and so on. The only thing that doesn't happen is that on the new sheets, the column widths are all standard 8.43, and I need them to be as they are on the input page. I tried researching it, but get only format painter advice - I want automatic!(:

Comment: You have to add it by using `GetSheet.Range("D2:G2").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth=10` or whichever width you would like.

Comment: VBA Pete: you're awesome. Why is it that I feel cleverer and more stupid at the same time?